# Write multi-line statement on single line

Tags: purescript

In Haskell I can write a multi-line statement on a single line, like

```
do {x<-[1,2];y<-[3,4];return (x,y)}
```

but in Purescript even a single-statement do-statement with curly braces will not compile. Is there different syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PureScript has no syntax for doing this kind of thing. Aside from just not using `do` ;)

```
[1, 2] >>= \x -> [3, 4] >>= \y -> pure (Tuple x y)
```