# Executing multi-line statements in python in interactive mode

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to the world of Python, and this is my first program in Python. I come from the world of R so this is a bit unintuitive to me.

When I execute

```
In[15]: import math
   ...: import random
   ...: random.random()
   ...: math.sqrt(85)
   ...:
```

in interactive mode (i.e. on `>>>` prompt), I get the output of `math.sqrt()`. I don't see the random number at all. However, when I execute `random.random()` and `math.sqrt()` separately, I do get both the results. Why is this? How do I get both the results? I am asking this because I have the habit of selecting multiple lines in R and executing them in interactive mode, especially when I am trying to debug code. Executing only one line at a time will be excruciating when trying to debug, say, 2000-line code.

Here's what happens when I select multiple lines in R and then execute them:

```
runif(1,0,1)
  sqrt(85)
```

It automatically parses these lines and generates the following output:

```
> runif(1,0,1)
[1] 0.01597949
>   sqrt(85)
[1] 9.219544
```

I researched on SO and found [Write multi-line statement on single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461251/write-multi-line-statement-on-single-line). I am unsure how to use the official answer from this thread.

---

Here's the output on PyCharm:

```
import math
import random
random.random()
math.sqrt(85)
Out[15]: 9.219544457292887
```

I am looking for some mechanism to see a random number and the sqrt of 85 without having to add any separator `,` or `;`, as I did in R code. I'd appreciate any thoughts.

**Expected Input:** One would run the code using "Execute Selection using Console" in PyCharm [Keyboard Shortcut: Alt + Shift + E]

```
import math
import random
random.random()
math.sqrt(85)
```

*[Please note that I haven't used any separator ";" or ","--just as we do in R]*

**Expected Output:**

```
random.random()
Out[16]: 0.183145720117748
math.sqrt(85)
Out[17]: 9.219544457292887
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not seeing the random number? In the Python prompt, on Python 2.7, doing `random.random()` just prints out a random number [0.0, 1.0).

Comment: @Mike- I just wanted to print a random number and the sqrt. However, Python only printed the sqrt. I didn't see random number at all.

Comment: You provided also your input, but could you also provide your expected output in the format you desire? Perhaps that'll clear up some confusion 

Comment: @Miket - Thanks again for your help. I have added expected output and input, and keyboard shortcut in PyCharm.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate your behavior in pycharm, even in the console. Have you tried this code in the python console through a basic Terminal window?

Comment: @Miket - You are right. In basic python console, it would execute every line by itself, but not so in PyCharm. Do you want me to post screenshot from PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons you are probably seeing the output of `math.sqrt()` only is because by default ipython/jupyter will only give you output of the last line of a multiline command. Python interpreter executes code line by line and any statement like `random.random()` which are not explicitly printed are just evaluated and thrown away. Ipython/Jupyter **by default** gets the result of the last line and displays it. I have not used pycharm but it probably does the same thing. To see the output of random.random() you have two options:

1) Use a print statement like below.

```
In [1]: import math
import random
print random.random()
math.sqrt(5)
   ...: 
0.145504928627
Out[1]: 2.23606797749979

In [2]:
```

2) Change the default behavior by changing the `ast_node_interactivity` parameter as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result)

```
In [1]: from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

In [2]: InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

In [3]: import math
import random
random.random()
math.sqrt(5)
   ...: 
Out[3]: 0.9772320535532782
Out[3]: 2.23606797749979
```

IPython has a variety of magic commands like `%edit` and `%load` which allows you to directly edit the commands in your favorite editor or load specific lines of code from a file like below. This can help with your requirement of selecting specific sections of your long code and running them separately. Below I have saved the above lines in a file called `test_interpreter.py`.

```
In [1]: !cat test_interpreter.py
import math
import random
print random.random()
math.sqrt(5)

In [2]: load -r 1-4 test_interpreter.py

In [3]: # %load -r 1-4 test_interpreter.py
import math
import random
print random.random()
math.sqrt(5)
   ...: 
0.719244573423
Out[3]: 2.23606797749979
```

The python REPL in unix shells by default does not support multiline commands (as far as I know of) but you can use `;` to terminate and start a new line with `\` which is escape character for `readline` which python REPL uses.

```
>>> import math;\
... import random;\
... random.random();\
... math.sqrt(5)
0.10298483416372617
2.23606797749979
```

In both normal python interpreter and ipython you can however directly copy paste lines from your editor and they will be evaluated separately like below.

```
#Copy paste four lines together
>>> import math
>>> import random
>>> random.random()
0.16039452147586075
>>> math.sqrt(5)
2.23606797749979
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I liked the approach for `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"`. Is there any way I can add this code to profile file or in PyCharm so that I don't have to copy-paste the same code again for every script? I come from R world, and executing a block of code is very common in R Programming. I tried adding `ipython_config.py` to `..\.ipython\profile_default` on Win machine, but nothing happened. I even restarted my PyCharm, but no luck. Today is my first day with Python. I'd appreciate your help. I am using Anaconda on PyCharm.

Comment: If you generated the `ipython_config.py` file in a standard way by entering `ipython profile create` from cmd then that file should contain a commented line like `# c.TerminalInteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr'`. Change `last_expr` to `all` and uncomment the line. Then restarting ipython should work. If the above line is not present then type it in manually. There should be an uncommented line like `c = get_config()` at the top of this file for all this to work though.

Comment: very respectfully, I have been trying to search and understand how to run `ipython profile create`. When I run that `ipython` command (i.e. Win + R and then I would type above command), I get Windows cannot find `ipython`. Is there anything you could point me to? This is my first day. So, I am very sorry.

Comment: I do not use Windows but if you installed ipython through anaconda `conda install ipython` it should put the ipython command in your path. Type Win + R and cmd to open a DOS shell first. Then type the above command. Normally the executable (`ipython.exe`) is located inside the `Scripts` folder in the Anaconda installation folder. If not in your path you can navigate there and run it as `ipython profile create`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Python 2.7.10 console, doing the following: importing math and random, getting a random number, and taking a square root of a number outputs as such:

```
>>> import math
>>> import random
>>> random.random()
0.52350453737542
>>> math.sqrt(85)
9.219544457292887
```

If you want both values to be printed contiguously, you can write multiple-line statements separated by the semi-colon operator:

```
>>> import math
>>> import random
>>> random.random(); math.sqrt(85)
0.9031053664569808
9.219544457292887
```

Comment: Thanks Miket. Is there any way to execute these statements without using separator with the exception of new line character?  As you can see in my post, I didn't add any separator except newline character between lines